# Distributing emacs packages with module functionality

Tags: package, modules

How to distribute an emacs package via Elpa that includes OSX and Linux module written in C that needs to be compiled locally?

Comment: I'm afraid there is little integration so far: https://github.com/aaptel/emacs-dynamic-module/issues/5